# .NET 5 Projects with Packaging Projects fail to build after VS2019 Upgrade to version 16.10

Tags: visual-studio-2019, setup-project, setup-deployment, msix

Following issue occurs only on **.NET Desktop Projects** that also include [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net).

After my `VS2019` was [updated to version 16.10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes), all my .NET 5 projects that also include a `Windows Application Packaging Project` fail to build in `VS2019`. Both the `Clean Solution` and `Rebuild Solution` actions fail. In both cases we get the following error:

> `ResolvePackageDependencies` task failed unexpectedly

When I tried `dotnet clean` I got the following error:

> `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

And I verified on my `Windows 10 Pro - latest version 20H2` that the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Microsoft\` does not have the `DesktopBridge` folder - and that seem to cause the issue. Both the `Clean Solution` and `Rebuild Solution` were working fine just before an upgrade of VS2019 to version 16.10

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, hope to find a solution asap. So far I know re-creating the packaging project solves the problem but I prefer to upgrade the projects instead.